# Ruby on Rails CSS not loading via assets pipeline

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have searched the web for a solution to this problem and haven't found a solution that works albeit I did find similar problems.

So, I am new to RoR development and this is my first app. I am try to create a page and have so far managed to route to my first page using a controller with an action. The routing works fine.

The problem is with the CSS, I have placed the css in a separate .css file within assets/stylesheets/main.css.

Here it is:

```
h1 {
   font-size: 100px;
}
```

I link to all stylesheets using the default method provided by Rails, it is placed in my application.html.erb file like so:

```
.
.
.
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'default', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
.
.
.
```

From my research, I have learnt that the assets pipeline allows you to place all of your CSS in the assets/stylesheet directory (and JS in the JS directory etc.). Rails should then use these CSS files automatically.

But this isn't working for me as the index.html.erb file stays the same as it would without the main.css when I run the app.

Any help would be appreciated.

Let me know if you require further information.

Thank you.

P.S. Using Rails 5.0.5 and ruby 2.2.6p396 (2016-11-15 revision 56800) [i386-mingw32] on Windows 10

P.P.S. I should note that `<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'default', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>` was previously `<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>`. I had to use default as using application threw an exception (ExecJS::ProgramError)

Comment: Its most likely a simple typo - `stylesheet_link_tag 'default'` would link to a file named `default.css` not `main`. I'm guessing you have both since sprockets is not throwing an error.

Comment: @max I have added default.css but doing so results in an exception.ExecJS::ProgramError in Welcome#index

Comment: use `<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'main', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>`. If you are getting `ExecJS::ProgramError` you're doing something very screwy which is messing up the assets pipeline.  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-stylesheet_link_tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the problem was with the installation of Node.js.

1. Visit https://nodejs.org/en/download/
2. Download and install current version
3. Restart computer after installation completes
4. Re run server, the problem should be gone and the app should run **without any modifications.** i.e. changing from application to default when specifying CSS files.

Visit https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l04kFL3pnEk for a step by step video tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

> ### `stylesheet_link_tag(*sources)`
>
> Returns a stylesheet link tag for the sources specified as arguments.
>   If you don't specify an extension, .css will be appended
>   automatically. You can modify the link attributes by passing a hash as
>   the last argument.
>   http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-stylesheet_link_tag

To link to `app/assets/stylesheets/main.css` you need to use `<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'main', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>`

Comment: Created a new project just to make sure I'm not doing anything screwy with the assets pipeline. I still get ExecJS::ProgramError.